# How to pass windows authentication from asp.net application to TFS 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm creating a asp.net web application which uses AD authentication to login.
This application provides some services which call TFS RestApi that uses AD authentication as well.
I need to pass login information to TFS and I don't want to keep username/password at all after signing.
Is there any way just to pass for example a current session token or identity to TFS Rest Api?
Somehow similar to SSO?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PatrickLu mentioned we need to enable impersonation in web.config.
Another thing, if you use HttpClient since it's async it's not gonna work:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials=true})
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("your-tfs-url").Result;
```

So it's better to use WebClient

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();              
 wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 wc.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; 
 charset=utf-8");                       
 var result=wc.DownloadString("http://yourtfs-url");
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, if it was resolved, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the answer easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

You could try below ways to do this:

- Using [ASP.NET impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- Store the TFS credential in a database or secure place and use
  [TFS impersonation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2009/12/04/introducing-tfs-impersonation/) in code to connect to TFS
- Create a WCF service that runs under the security of the TFS
  credentials. This WCF service will make the TFS query. From your web
  application you can call this WCF service.

**Note:**

1. *For way 1, have a look at this tutorial: [Setting up impersonation
   for ASP.NET TFS API apps](http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/rorystreet/2015/06/24/SettingUpImpersonationForASPNETTFSAPIApps.aspx)*
2. *For way 2, this also requires TFS Admin to make some
       settings(impersonate of TFS)*

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please correct me if I'm wrong.Your solution works under having one TFS credential for all users. Every windows user has access to TFS and I want to impersonate per user. Calling TFS rest api with each user credential without storing them.

Comment: The solution didn't work in the beginning for me since I had used HttpClient.After using WebClient it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @alirezam Glad to here this, always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works!:) You could add your solution here as a reply and mark it, which will also help other in the community later.